# Showing that $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(H)| \le |\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)|$ where $H \le G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am having trouble with the following problem and would really appreciate a *hint* on how to go about proving this.

Let $H$ be an arbitrary subgroup of a finite group $G$.  Show that $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(H)| \le |\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)|$.

In particular, I would like to construct an injective map from $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(H)|$ to $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)|$.

Let $P \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$.  Then $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and by one of Sylow's theorems it is contained in some $P' \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$.  Let $\phi: \mathrm{Syl}_p(H) \to \mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$ be given by $\phi(P)=P'$ for such a pair of subgroups of $G$.

This seems like the most natural map to consider in this situation - is it the map I want to be considering?

I have not been able to show that this map is injective.  I have set up the usual way to show this: Let $P_1, P_2 \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$ with $P_1 \ne P_2$ and let $S \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$.  Suppose that $\phi(P_1)=S=\phi(P_2)$.  Now I need some way to show that, in fact, $P_1=P_2$.  I tried deriving some contradiction, such as the product $P_1P_2$ being larger than $S$, or something along those lines.  However, I think with $H$ an arbitrary subgroup we don't have enough to go on for this.  I haven't been able to come up with any other ideas.

I'd appreciate help on what direction to go in with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $P_H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, then $P_H = P_G \cap H$, where $P_G$ is some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Note that in general $P_G \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$ does not imply that $P_G \cap H \in \operatorname{Syl}_p(H)$. (However, this is true if you assume that $H$ is a normal subgroup)

Comment: For the first part, can we argue like this?: Let $P \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$.  Then $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and so it is contained in some member of $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$, say $S$.  Then $H \cap S = P$ - since it must contain $P$, and if it contained any other elements of $H$ it would be a $p$-subgroup of $H$ larger than $P$, leading to a contradiction that $P \in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$.

Comment: Also, how do we show the second part?

Comment: @AlexPetzke: Yes, that proof works. With the second part, do you mean the case where $H$ is normal? You can apply $PH/H \cong P / P \cap H$ there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  I will work that out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you tell me what fact we are able to derive from the above isomorphism result that shows us that $P \cap H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$?  For example, are we able to show from that result that $\gcd(|H|/|P \cap H|,p)=1$?

Comment: Yes, that isomorphism gives $[PH : P] = [H : P \cap H]$ so $p$ does not divide $[H : P \cap H]$.

Comment: Or you could just use the usual formula for the order of $PH$. The essential thing here is that $PH$ is a subgroup, so $[PH : P]$ makes sense.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me why we know that $|PH:P|$ is not divisible by $p$ - could you explain?

Comment: Suppose that $P$ has order $p^\alpha$. Now if $[PH : P]$ is divisible by $p$, then the order of $G$ is divisible by $p^{\alpha+1}$, a contradiction because $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Define a map from $\text{Syl}_p(G)$ to the set of $p$-subgroups of $H$. Show that the image contains $\text{Syl}_p(H)$.

Answer (score 2):

Bonus information: there is a [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-10/S0002-9939-03-06884-9/S0002-9939-03-06884-9.pdf) of prof Gabriel Navarro from 2003 that implies that for a *solvable* group $G$, and any prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, $n_p(H) \mid n_p(G)$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$. Here $n_p(X)=\#Syl_p(X)$ (which is understood to be $1$ if $p \nmid |X|$).